# Why are there separate "white-box" and "white-box-testing" tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

[white-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/white-box)

> White-box testing is a method of testing software that tests internal structures or workings of an application as opposed to its functionality i.e. black-box testing

[white-box-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/white-box-testing)

> White box testing is a process of giving the input and checking how the given input is been processed to obtain the output from the system.

Given these tag definitions, they sound pretty much exactly the same. I wanted to write a question about white box testing and so I used both tags as I couldn't work out which was preferable. Looking through both tag lists, it seems several other users have done the same.

Could these be made into synonyms? I'm not a frequent MSO user, I don't know whether this needs to be a "burnination" request - please advise if so.

**EDIT:**

I realise that the same problem exists for [black-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/black-box) and [black-box-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/black-box-testing). The definitions below:

[black-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/black-box)

> A black box is a device, system or object which can be viewed in terms of its input, output and transfer characteristics without any knowledge of its internal workings.

[black-box-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/black-box-testing)

> "Black box" testing tests a device, program, application, etc., as a whole. Inputs are provided and the results monitored. The internal workings of the tested item are not relevant and may be unknown. "Functional testing" is a type of "Black box testing", but not all "black box" tests have to be "functional".

**Suggestion:** [black-box-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/black-box-testing) is the main tag, with [black-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/black-box) as a synonym. And [white-box-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/white-box-testing) is the main tag, with [white-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/white-box) as a synonym.

Comment: Should definitely be at least synonyms. The usage of [[tag:white-box]] starts with *"White-box testing is ..."*

Comment: I can totally see [tag:white-box] being combined with [tag:css]. Oh boy, [that is not even a joke](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwhite-box%5D+%5Bcss%5D+is%3Aq&searchOn=3). I see myself out...

Comment: I'd forgive these questions for been a decade old. Honestly, it's suprising that it's only been these two

Comment: I kind of wonder what the point is of tagging a question white-box-test. The other tags on such a question would already very much imply that it is about that subject.

Comment: It at least appears that *clear* misuse is fairly rare. [Searching for uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/white-box+-*testing*) of the [[tag:white-box]] tag *without* some other tag mentioning "testing" is uncommon, only 15 hits this moment. Though there is one Q tagged both [white-box] *and* [black-box].

Comment: I think we should make [[tag:white-box]] a synonym of [[tag:white-box-testing]], since the "testing" variant is the more specific term. Could help prevent [the silly misuse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKCvE.png) mentioned by rene in the future.

Comment: I've just realised that the same problem exists for [tag:black-box] and [tag:black-box-testing] ... maybe both [tag:black-box] and [tag:white-box] should be amalgamated into [tag:black-box-testing] and [tag:white-box-testing] respectively

Comment: I like rene's idea better.

Comment: Title suggestion: "Every tag is not always [black-box] and [white-box]"

Comment: As usual with these things, the number of users that are allowed to propose and vote on such synonyms approaches 0 as the obviousness of the synonyms approaches 1. We really need a better way to deal with tag synonyms.

Comment: @CrisLuengo there's a way: manual retag.

Comment: @Braiam: That doesn't create a synonym though.

Comment: @CrisLuengo While technically you are correct, the system is smart enough to suggest you both tags when you type "white-box" on the tag field. If you do this manually, someone would have to create the tag for it to become an issue again. I'm just pointing out a solution that will do what we want (1 tag instead of 2) and will put a barrier for the usage of the other undesired tag.

Comment: @Lou The [tag:black-box] tag isn't a duplicate of [tag:black-box-testing]; see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/62338990/5223757.