# “Posts containing 'is:q'” should not be in the window title

Tags: bug, search

When I go to https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwhite-box%5D+%5Bcss%5D+is%3Aq (a search on Stack Overflow for questions that contain [white-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/white-box) and [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)), then the title of the browser tab (i.e. the `<title>`) reads

```
Posts containing 'is:q' - Stack Overflow
```

[image: The browser tab has the title “Posts containing 'is:q' - Stack Overflow”.]

As is obvious by the results, this is for posts that *are* questions, not *contain* `is:q`. Although not a big problem, I think it should be fixed so that it doesn’t contain that in the title.

Comment: Not really a big issue, though, is it? Not something I'd want the devs to prioritise over more pressing search improvements.

Comment: @MartijnPieters More pressing search improvements? Not something I'd want the devs to prioritise when there's Google. :p

Comment: @Nick: Google can't return deleted posts, or let me filter by score or userid or URL. Both have their uses!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Of course I don't know much about the underlying logic of Stack Overflow, but I would be thinking this is a bit simple to fix.  But yes, this doesn't need much priority at all.

Comment: Maybe the real bug is the removal of the tags I searched for.  (I know that search)

Comment: @rene: Yes, that's the search from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405546/.  The comment you posted on it: *I can totally see [white-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/white-box) being combined with [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css). Oh boy, [that is not even a joke](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwhite-box%5D+%5Bcss%5D+is%3Aq&searchOn=3). I see myself out... – rene [yesterday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405546/why-are-there-separate-white-box-and-white-box-testing-tags?cb=1#comment827243_405546)*

Comment: For what it's worth, this isn't specific to "is". The title isn't adjusted for any of the operators.

Comment: The easiest fix would probably be to change the text "Posts containing" to "Query for".

Comment: How did this warrant a post on meta? It's so trivial yet probably a big deal for devs to fix.

Comment: @10Rep - well, where should one post a report if not on Meta? Don't see the reason why not report it (although this is indeed an extremely minor thing and is likely to get added to an already enormous pile of things to fix/improve/change...). Kinda curious why someone certainly had the insight to filter out tags but chose not to handle search operators the same way

Comment: Dunno about dev time, but it's a good catch.